# Fragment not being deleted after calling .remove(fragment)

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentmanager

I am overriding the `onBackPressed` function to change the behavior of the back key for an app I am working on.

If a the FragmentTransaction contains a fragment with a certain tag `qFrag` then I want it to animate the fragment from the view.

However after I remove the fragment, it still appears to be there. Because of this it never reaches the `else` condition of my if statement.

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // After pressing the back key a second time, questionFrag still has a value.
    Fragment questionFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("qFrag");

    // If question fragment in the fragment manager
    if (questionFrag != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down)
                .replace(R.id.main_menu_content_frame_layout, new Fragment(), "temp")
                .remove(questionFrag)
                .commit();

    } else {
        finish();
    }

}
```

Can someone advise me on how to appropriately remove fragments from the transaction manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you need to know about fragments in this subject:

1 - When you give a tag to a fragment and add it to back stack which you most certainly are, this:

```
Fragment questionFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("qFrag");
```

only returns null if you call `popBackStack()`. Since you are not calling it the fragment is still stored in the backstack even if you call remove on it.

2- This bit of code

```
.replace(R.id.main_menu_content_frame_layout, new Fragment(), "temp")
.remove(questionFrag)
```

is redundat since when you call `replace` you are calling remove on every fragment that is in the given container, and then add the new one so this

```
.replace(R.id.main_menu_content_frame_layout, new Fragment(), "temp")
```

is enough.

Now, there are two ways too solve your problem which are:

poping the back stack after replace:

```
if (questionFrag != null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.main_menu_content_frame_layout, new Fragment(), "temp")
        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down)
        .commit();

     getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();    

     System.out.println("questionFrag removed successfully");

    finish()
} else {
    finish();
}
```

Or, instead of poping the backstack, verify if the fragment is in the container

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_menu_content_frame_layout);

if(fragment instanceOf QuestionFragment){
     getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.main_menu_content_frame_layout, new Fragment(), "temp")
        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down)
        .commit();

     getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();    

     System.out.println("questionFrag removed successfully");

    finish()

} else {
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Been struggling with the topic and this certainly helps.

Comment: It does't help me. It's still has ( it can be find by Tag ) after remove , commitNow, and popBackStack().

Answer (score 0):

Try this, call .remove first, then add the new fragment (not replace, since .remove will empty the container), then set your custom animation:

```
if (questionFrag != null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .remove(questionFrag)
            .add(R.id.main_menu_content_frame_layout, new Fragment(), "temp")
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down)
            .commit();

            System.out.println("questionFrag removed successfully");

            finish()
} else {
    finish();
}
```

You could add the system.out to check which point the code reaches, it's a good way to find errors. If you don't see the print out in your log, you'll know the FragmentManager code isn't executing properly.